# Why does -A (aaa) analysis show much more information, when using the -d (debug) CLI option in Radare2?

Tags: disassembly, debugging, radare2, static-analysis

> Why does -A (aaa) analysis show much more information, when using the -d (debug) CLI option in Radare2?

I'm using the newest version of Radare2 to analyze the Windows application.

As can be seen below, using the -d (debug) option with -A (aaa) yields more information on the application, e.g. symbols. Why is that?

Without the -d (debug) CLI option:

```
$ r2 -A WindowsService.exe
Metadata Signature: 0x8bc 0x10001424a5342 12
.NET Version: v4.0.30319
[x] Analyze all flags starting with sym. and entry0 (aa)
[x] Analyze function calls (aac)
[x] Analyze len bytes of instructions for references (aar)
[x] Constructing a function name for fcn.* and sym.func.* functions (aan)
[x] Type matching analysis for all functions (afta)
[x] Use -AA or aaaa to perform additional experimental analysis.
 -- I didn't say that it was working, I said that it's implemented
[0x00403e92]> afll
address    size  nbbs edges    cc cost  min bound range max bound  calls locals args xref frame name
========== ==== ===== ===== ===== ==== ========== ===== ========== ===== ====== ==== ==== ===== ====
0x00403e92    6     1     0     1    3 0x00403e92     6 0x00403e98     0    0      0    1     0 entry0
```

With the -d (debug) CLI option:

```
$ r2 -d -A WindowsService.exe
Process with PID 21499 started...
= attach 21499 21499
bin.baddr 0x561296b89000
Using 0x561296b89000
asm.bits 64
[x] Analyze all flags starting with sym. and entry0 (aa)
[x] Analyze function calls (aac)
[x] Analyze len bytes of instructions for references (aar)
[x] Constructing a function name for fcn.* and sym.func.* functions (aan)
[TOFIX: afta can't run in debugger mode.ions (afta)
[x] Type matching analysis for all functions (afta)
[x] Use -AA or aaaa to perform additional experimental analysis.
= attach 21499 21499
21499
 -- Use zoom.byte=entropy and press 'z' in visual mode to zoom out to see the entropy of the whole file
[0x7fb177974090]> afll
address            size  nbbs edges    cc cost          min bound range max bound          calls locals args xref frame name
================== ==== ===== ===== ===== ==== ================== ===== ================== ===== ====== ==== ==== ===== ====
0x0000561296b89000  285     3     2     3  134 0x0000561296b89000   292 0x0000561296b89124     0    0      1    0    24 sym.imp.__libc_start_main
0x0000561296b8d290    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d290     6 0x0000561296b8d296     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.sigprocmask
0x0000561296b8d2a0    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d2a0     6 0x0000561296b8d2a6     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.raise
0x0000561296b8d2b0    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d2b0     6 0x0000561296b8d2b6     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.free
0x0000561296b8d2c0    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d2c0     6 0x0000561296b8d2c6     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.strcasecmp
0x0000561296b8d2d0    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d2d0     6 0x0000561296b8d2d6     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.abort
0x0000561296b8d2e0    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d2e0     6 0x0000561296b8d2e6     0    0      0    1     0 sym.imp.__errno_location
0x0000561296b8d2f0    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d2f0     6 0x0000561296b8d2f6     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp._exit
0x0000561296b8d300    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d300     6 0x0000561296b8d306     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.strcpy
0x0000561296b8d310    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d310     6 0x0000561296b8d316     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.qsort
0x0000561296b8d320    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d320     6 0x0000561296b8d326     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.isatty
0x0000561296b8d330    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d330     6 0x0000561296b8d336     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.sigaction
0x0000561296b8d340    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d340     6 0x0000561296b8d346     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.strtod
0x0000561296b8d350    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d350     6 0x0000561296b8d356     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.strchrnul
0x0000561296b8d360    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d360     6 0x0000561296b8d366     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.faccessat
0x0000561296b8d370    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d370     6 0x0000561296b8d376     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.fcntl
0x0000561296b8d380    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d380     6 0x0000561296b8d386     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.write
0x0000561296b8d390    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d390     6 0x0000561296b8d396     0    0      0    1     0 sym.imp.getpid
0x0000561296b8d3a0    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d3a0     6 0x0000561296b8d3a6     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.__strtol_internal
0x0000561296b8d3b0    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d3b0     6 0x0000561296b8d3b6     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.__xstat64
0x0000561296b8d3c0    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d3c0     6 0x0000561296b8d3c6     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.wait3
0x0000561296b8d3d0    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d3d0     6 0x0000561296b8d3d6     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.opendir
0x0000561296b8d3e0    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d3e0     6 0x0000561296b8d3e6     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.stpcpy
0x0000561296b8d3f0    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d3f0     6 0x0000561296b8d3f6     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.strlen
0x0000561296b8d400    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d400     6 0x0000561296b8d406     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.chdir
0x0000561296b8d410    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d410     6 0x0000561296b8d416     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.__stack_chk_fail
0x0000561296b8d420    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d420     6 0x0000561296b8d426     0    0      0    1     0 sym.imp.getuid
0x0000561296b8d430    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d430     6 0x0000561296b8d436     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.dup2
0x0000561296b8d440    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d440     6 0x0000561296b8d446     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.strchr
0x0000561296b8d450    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d450     6 0x0000561296b8d456     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.warnx
0x0000561296b8d460    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d460     6 0x0000561296b8d466     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.__strtoul_internal
0x0000561296b8d470    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d470     6 0x0000561296b8d476     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.fnmatch
0x0000561296b8d480    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d480     6 0x0000561296b8d486     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.geteuid
0x0000561296b8d490    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d490     6 0x0000561296b8d496     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.getcwd
0x0000561296b8d4a0    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d4a0     6 0x0000561296b8d4a6     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.close
0x0000561296b8d4b0    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d4b0     6 0x0000561296b8d4b6     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.pipe
0x0000561296b8d4c0    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d4c0     6 0x0000561296b8d4c6     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.strspn
0x0000561296b8d4d0    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d4d0     6 0x0000561296b8d4d6     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.closedir
0x0000561296b8d4e0    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d4e0     6 0x0000561296b8d4e6     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.strcspn
0x0000561296b8d4f0    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d4f0     6 0x0000561296b8d4f6     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.read
0x0000561296b8d500    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d500     6 0x0000561296b8d506     0    0      0    1     0 sym.imp._setjmp
0x0000561296b8d510    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d510     6 0x0000561296b8d516     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.execve
0x0000561296b8d520    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d520     6 0x0000561296b8d526     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.__fxstat64
0x0000561296b8d530    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d530     6 0x0000561296b8d536     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.strcmp
0x0000561296b8d540    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d540     6 0x0000561296b8d546     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.signal
0x0000561296b8d550    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d550     6 0x0000561296b8d556     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.getpwnam
0x0000561296b8d560    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d560     6 0x0000561296b8d566     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.umask
0x0000561296b8d570    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d570     6 0x0000561296b8d576     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.strtol
0x0000561296b8d580    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d580     6 0x0000561296b8d586     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.sigfillset
0x0000561296b8d590    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d590     6 0x0000561296b8d596     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.memcpy
0x0000561296b8d5a0    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d5a0     6 0x0000561296b8d5a6     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.kill
0x0000561296b8d5b0    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d5b0     6 0x0000561296b8d5b6     0    0      0    1     0 sym.imp.getgid
0x0000561296b8d5c0    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d5c0     6 0x0000561296b8d5c6     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.tcgetpgrp
0x0000561296b8d5d0    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d5d0     6 0x0000561296b8d5d6     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.__xstat
0x0000561296b8d5e0    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d5e0     6 0x0000561296b8d5e6     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.readdir
0x0000561296b8d5f0    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d5f0     6 0x0000561296b8d5f6     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.malloc
0x0000561296b8d600    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d600     6 0x0000561296b8d606     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.killpg
0x0000561296b8d610    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d610     6 0x0000561296b8d616     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.getegid
0x0000561296b8d620    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d620     6 0x0000561296b8d626     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.strpbrk
0x0000561296b8d630    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d630     6 0x0000561296b8d636     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.sigsuspend
0x0000561296b8d640    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d640     6 0x0000561296b8d646     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.__vsnprintf_chk
0x0000561296b8d650    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d650     6 0x0000561296b8d656     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.setrlimit
0x0000561296b8d660    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d660     6 0x0000561296b8d666     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.strsignal
0x0000561296b8d670    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d670     6 0x0000561296b8d676     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.realloc
0x0000561296b8d680    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d680     6 0x0000561296b8d686     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.sigsetmask
0x0000561296b8d690    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d690     6 0x0000561296b8d696     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.__longjmp_chk
0x0000561296b8d6a0    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d6a0     6 0x0000561296b8d6a6     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.open64
0x0000561296b8d6b0    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d6b0     6 0x0000561296b8d6b6     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.mempcpy
0x0000561296b8d6c0    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d6c0     6 0x0000561296b8d6c6     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.memmove
0x0000561296b8d6d0    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d6d0     6 0x0000561296b8d6d6     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.setgid
0x0000561296b8d6e0    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d6e0     6 0x0000561296b8d6e6     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.getpgrp
0x0000561296b8d6f0    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d6f0     6 0x0000561296b8d6f6     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.tcsetpgrp
0x0000561296b8d700    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d700     6 0x0000561296b8d706     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.open
0x0000561296b8d710    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d710     6 0x0000561296b8d716     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.times
0x0000561296b8d720    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d720     6 0x0000561296b8d726     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.strtok
0x0000561296b8d730    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d730     6 0x0000561296b8d736     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.sysconf
0x0000561296b8d740    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d740     6 0x0000561296b8d746     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.__lxstat64
0x0000561296b8d750    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d750     6 0x0000561296b8d756     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.setpgid
0x0000561296b8d760    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d760     6 0x0000561296b8d766     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.getppid
0x0000561296b8d770    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d770     6 0x0000561296b8d776     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.getrlimit
0x0000561296b8d780    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d780     6 0x0000561296b8d786     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.setuid
0x0000561296b8d790    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d790     6 0x0000561296b8d796     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.strdup
0x0000561296b8d7a0    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d7a0     6 0x0000561296b8d7a6     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.strerror
0x0000561296b8d7b0    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d7b0     6 0x0000561296b8d7b6     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.fork
0x0000561296b8d7c0    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d7c0     6 0x0000561296b8d7c6     0    0      0    0     0 sym.imp.__ctype_b_loc
0x0000561296b8d7d0    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000561296b8d7d0     6 0x0000561296b8d7d6     0    0      0    1     0 sub.__cxa_finalize_7d0
0x0000561296b8d850  455    25    42    17  155 0x0000561296b8d850   455 0x0000561296b8da17    20    6      2    1   280 main
0x0000561296b8da20   43     1     0     1   17 0x0000561296b8da20    43 0x0000561296b8da4b     1    0      1    0     8 entry0
0x0000561296b8da50   40     4     4     4   19 0x0000561296b8da50    50 0x0000561296b8da82     0    0      0    1     8 sub.__environ_32_a50
0x0000561296b8da90   57     4     4     4   24 0x0000561296b8da90    66 0x0000561296b8dad2     0    0      0    1     8 loc.561296b8da90
0x0000561296b8dae0   51     5     5     4   24 0x0000561296b8dae0    58 0x0000561296b8db1a     2    0      0    0     0 entry2.fini
0x0000561296b8db20  124     5     5     4   30 0x0000561296b8da90    10 0x0000561296b8db2a     0    0      0    0     8 entry1.init
0x0000561296da5fd8   72     1     0     1   33 0x0000561296da5fd8    72 0x0000561296da6020     0    0      0    1     0 reloc.__libc_start_main
```

Answer (score 2):

It is probably due to the fact that you are trying to use `r2` - a native disassembler/debugger to a .NET assembly which written in managed language and executed under CLR - Common Language Runtime. This line from your output gives that away

> .NET Version: v4.0.30319

How .NET works is, that before execution, there should be no user provided native code (there are some exceptions that one can force compilation to a native platform) and only an entry point is visible - which you see without debugging. After running the file - it starts from the entry point and by using a `JIT` (Just-in-time compiler) compiling the `IL` to native code on the platform you are running on. This might be the reason you see all those methods when you list them while debugging.

I suggest you use a decompiler/debugger suited for .NET assemblies such as [dnSpy](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnSpy).

Comment: Thank you - sounds reasonable. By "user provided native code", you mean e.g. x86 machine code emitted by a compiler?

Comment: Yes. There might be only some compiler generated code.